# Вставка текста в textarea по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

На странице есть несколько полей для комментария, пытаюсь сделать смайлы для комментариев. Не получается разбить по отдельность для каждого поля, смайлы вставляются сразу во все поля.

```
<textarea class="smile"></textarea><br>
<img class="bc" data-smile=":angel_mini:" src="http://s61.radikal.ru/i174/1606/aa/dabfb9195551.gif">
<img class="bc" data-smile=":biggrin_mini2:" src="http://i057.radikal.ru/1606/16/5bf2dba48195.gif">
<hr>
<textarea class="smile"></textarea><br>
<img class="bc" data-smile=":angel_mini:" src="http://s61.radikal.ru/i174/1606/aa/dabfb9195551.gif">
<img class="bc" data-smile=":biggrin_mini2:" src="http://i057.radikal.ru/1606/16/5bf2dba48195.gif">

$('.bc').click(function(){
if($('textarea.smile').append($(this).data('smile') + '\n'));
});
```

Может есть другие варианты как это сделать? В `textarea` `id` прописать не могу.

Пример.

http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/QEbYBE

Ещё хороший пример, но только нужно несколько таких полей на одной странице.
http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/gMpZZd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само собой, они будут вставляться во все `textarea`, вы это и указываете делать: `$('textarea.smile') ...`

Как вариант, можно обернуть каждый `textarea` со смайлами в блок, например с классом `comment`. Затем, воспользовавшись [e.delegateTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/), узнавать в каком из блоков сработало событие `click`, и вставлять в дочерний `textarea` этого блока.

```js
$('.comment').on("click", ".bc", function(e){
  $(e.delegateTarget).find('.smile').append($(this).data('smile') + '\n');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment">
<textarea class="smile"></textarea><br>
<img class="bc" data-smile=":angel_mini:" src="http://s61.radikal.ru/i174/1606/aa/dabfb9195551.gif">
<img class="bc" data-smile=":biggrin_mini2:" src="http://i057.radikal.ru/1606/16/5bf2dba48195.gif">
</div>

<hr>

<div class="comment">
  <textarea class="smile"></textarea><br>
  <img class="bc" data-smile=":angel_mini:" src="http://s61.radikal.ru/i174/1606/aa/dabfb9195551.gif">
  <img class="bc" data-smile=":biggrin_mini2:" src="http://i057.radikal.ru/1606/16/5bf2dba48195.gif">
</div>
```